# Example of G and H in Banach Space s.t. $(G\cap H)^{\perp}\neq \overline{G^{\perp}+H^{\perp}}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to know example of G and H are closed subspaces of Banach space such that $(G\cap H)^{\perp}\neq \overline{(G^{\perp}+H^{\perp})}$

Here $G{\perp} $ is annihilator of G.

$G^{\perp}=\{f\in E^*|f(x)=0\forall x\in G\}$

I know that $\overline{G^{\perp}+H^{\perp}}\subset G\cap H  $ But i do not know example where strict inequality holds

I think the example where $Z^{\perp}\subset (Z^{\perp})^{\perp}$ will work But I did not know that

I do not know how to tackle such problem.If you also tell me how to find such example that would be really helpful for me.

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: You have to correct the title.

Comment: Is there some reason you think such an example should exist?

Comment: Dear Sir there is typo in questionPlease Help me I have edited question

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in G \cap H$ then $x \perp G^{\perp}$ and $x \perp H^{\perp}$ so $x \perp (G^{\perp}+H^{\perp})$. [ If $g \in G^{\perp}$ and $h \in H^{\perp}$ then $g$ vanishes at $x$ and so does $h$. Hence $(g+h)(x)=0$]. This proves that LHS $\subseteq$ RHS.

Answer for the revised question:

I will write $M^{\perp}$ for $(\{x \in E: f(x)=0 \forall f \in M\})$ for subspaces $M$ of the dual space. Then $(G^{\perp}+H^{\perp})^{\perp} \subseteq G \cap H$. Hence $(G \cap H)^{\perp} \subset \overline {G^{\perp}+H^{\perp}}$ which proves that the counterexample you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: Dear Sir this example is in hilbert space.I wanted to prove for Banach space.I do not have notion of orthogonality in that space .In book they had defined $G^{\perp}=\{f\in E^*|f(x)=0\forall x\in G\}$

Comment: I don't understand where your difficulty is. LHS being a subset of RHS is actually the easy part.

Comment: Dear Sir Extremely sorry There is huge typo inside question. i had written trivally false statement.Please Help me